# Insert JavaScript in Joomla external url

Tags: javascript, url, joomla, module, external

I want to trigger “pweb ajax popup contact form” module when I click on "contact to us" menu item and appear a popup contact form for user. Software developer say that make a external URL menu Item and in address link section insert this code

```
javascript:pwebContactID.toggleForm();
```

where ID is pweb Ajax module ID in joomla, now when I want to save this menu item, joomla 3.2.1  says “warning: save not permitted”. Anybody can help me or any suggestion to solve it.

Comment: This is probably a question better asked of the developer, whom you've paid for a viable product. I see that your code example is straight from their docs: http://www.perfect-web.co/joomla/ajax-contact-form-popup-module/documentation#doc18

Comment: I read all of that documents, but when I save the menu item (like this picture"http://www.perfect-web.co/images/joomla/modules/mod_pwebcontact/docs/open-form-with-menu-item.png"  joomal say "warning: save not permitted". there is a difference with me and pweb developer (how send this picture) or there is mistake of me. I don't no, what's problem? Can I help me.

Comment: It looks like you're doing it per the documentation, which is why I'd contact the developer. Looks like they need to update their product to match changes in Joomla's security protocol.